# How to create a custom type from some properties of a complex object?

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

I have the following type definitions as helpers:

```
type MapSchemaTypes = {
    string: string;
    number: number;
    integer: number;
    float: number;
    boolean: boolean;
};

type MapSchema<T extends Record<string, keyof MapSchemaTypes>> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: MapSchemaTypes[T[K]]
}
```

With that, I can generate a type from a simple object. For example:

```
const TestModel1 = {
    id: "number",
    lastname: "string",
    firstname: "string",
    valid: "boolean"
} as const;
type TestRecord1 = MapSchema<typeof TestModel1>;
```

Result is correct:

```
type TestRecord1 = {
    id: number;
    lastname: string;
    firstname: string;
    valid: boolean;
}
```

But now, I would like to generate the exact same type but from a more complex object:

```
const TestModel2 = {
    id: {
        type: "number",
        mapping: "_id",
        defaultValue: 0
    },
    lastname: {
        type: "string",
        mapping: "_lastname",
        defaultValue: ""
    },
    firstname: {
        type: "string",
        mapping: "_firstname",
        defaultValue: ""
    },
    valid: {
        type: "boolean",
        mapping: "_valid",
        defaultValue: false
    }
} as const;
type TestRecord2 = MapSchema<typeof TestModel2>;
```

Errors:

```
Type '{ readonly id: { readonly type: "number"; readonly mapping: "_id"; readonly defaultValue: 0; }; readonly lastname: { readonly type: "string"; readonly mapping: "_lastname"; readonly defaultValue: ""; }; readonly firstname: { ...; }; readonly valid: { ...; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, "string" | "number" | "boolean" | "integer" | "float">'.
Property 'id' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ readonly type: "number"; readonly mapping: "_id"; readonly defaultValue: 0; }' is not assignable to type '"string" | "number" | "boolean" | "integer" | "float"'.
    Type '{ readonly type: "number"; readonly mapping: "_id"; readonly defaultValue: 0; }' is not assignable to type '"float"'.ts(2344)
```

It obviously generates the wrong type:

```
type TestRecord2 = {
    id: unknown;
    lastname: unknown;
    firstname: unknown;
    valid: unknown;
}
```

And I cannot figure how to do it correctly. I know that I have to change the MapSchema type but everything I tried failed so far.

For example I tried:

```
type MapSchema<T extends Record<string, keyof MapSchemaTypes>> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: MapSchemaTypes[T[K]["type"]]
}
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Type 'T[K]["type"]' cannot be used to index type 'MapSchemaTypes'.ts(2536)
Type '"type"' cannot be used to index type 'T[K]'.ts(2536)
```

Or again:

```
type MapSchema<T extends Record<string, keyof MapSchemaTypes>> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: MapSchemaTypes[T[K].type]]
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot find name 'type'.ts(2304)
```

Is it even possible to achieve what I want to do?

## Update

Following @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir [very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64569975/1076652), here are my updated type helpers:

```
type MapSchemaTypes = {
    string: string;
    number: number;
    integer: number;
    float: number;
    boolean: boolean;
};
type MapSchemaDefaultValues = string | number | boolean | undefined | null;
type MapSchemaSimpleField   = keyof MapSchemaTypes;
type MapSchemaComplexField  = {
    type: MapSchemaSimpleField;
    mapping: string;
    defaultValue: MapSchemaDefaultValues
};
type MapSchemaField = MapSchemaSimpleField | MapSchemaComplexField;
type MapSchemaDefinition = Record<string, MapSchemaField>;
type MapSchema<T extends MapSchemaDefinition> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { type: infer TypeName } ? MapSchemaTypes[TypeName & MapSchemaSimpleField] : MapSchemaTypes[T[K] & MapSchemaSimpleField]
};
```

This lets me do the following:

```
const TestModel4 = {
    id: "number",
    lastname: {
        type: "string",
        mapping: "_lastname",
        defaultValue: ""
    },
    firstname: "string",
    valid: {
        type: "boolean",
        mapping: "_valid",
        defaultValue: false
    }
} as const;
type TestRecord4 = MapSchema<typeof TestModel4>;
```

And the resulting type is correct:

```
type TestRecord4 = {
    id: number;
    lastname: string;
    firstname: string;
    valid: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint you have on `T` is wrong if you want the properties of `T` to be an object with a type property, you should use  `Record<string, { type: keyof MapSchemaTypes }>`

```
type MapSchema<T extends Record<string, { type: keyof MapSchemaTypes }>> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: MapSchemaTypes[T[K]["type"]]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

If you want it to work for both complex objects and just the type name, you can use a union in the constraint and a conditional type to discriminate between the two casses:

```
type MapSchema<T extends Record<string, { type: keyof MapSchemaTypes } | keyof MapSchemaTypes>> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends { type: infer TypeName } ? MapSchemaTypes[TypeName &  keyof MapSchemaTypes] : MapSchemaTypes[T[K] & keyof MapSchemaTypes]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Wow, it works! Thanks a lot! Is there any way to make it work with both objects (TestModel1 and TestModel2) with the same MapSchema type?

Comment: @GabrielHautclocq expanded answer to include this scenario

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a genius!

Comment: I know I ask a lot, but would it be possible for the generated type to take the value of "mapping" (if present in object) as the type keys? For example it would generate a type like ```type TestRecord3 = {
    id: number;
    _lastname: string;
    firstname: string;
    _valid: boolean;
}```